# SQL query to return records filtered by week, month , quarter, year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the user and DateTime ( format: 12-OCT-22 01.15.23.000 AM). I need to get the user's count based on week, month, quarter, and year.

Like how many users per week, month, quarter, and year. In addition, to that eliminate duplicate records ( for example if a user's id registers twice in a week on the table records, we need to consider only one user) as well.

Need to write the SQL query for this.

```
ID1     12-OCT-22 01:40:56.880 AM
ID8     12-OCT-22 01:40:56.880 AM
ID6     12-OCT-22 01:40:56.880 AM
ID7     12-OCT-22 01:39:56.880 AM
ID4     12-OCT-22 01:38:56.880 AM
ID10    11-OCT-22 01:37:56.880 PM
ID43    11-OCT-22 01:36:56.880 PM
ID72    11-OCT-22 01:35:56.880 PM
.
.
.
Etc.
```

Note: I'm using PLSQL application and Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group by year try the code below, where T is the table that holds your data:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'YYYY'), COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'YYYY')
```

To group by week, replace `YYYY` with `WW`.
To group by month, replace `YYYY` with `MM`.
To group by quarter, replace `YYYY` with `Q`.
To count the distinct number of users then replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID)`

To combine all aggregation levels into one query, try the following

```
SELECT 
  'YEAR' "AGGREGATION LEVEL", TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'YYYY'), COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'YYYY')

 UNION

SELECT 
  'WEEK' "AGGREGATION LEVEL", TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'WW'), COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'WW')

 UNION

SELECT 
  'MONTH' "AGGREGATION LEVEL", TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'MM'), COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'MM')

 UNION

SELECT 
  'QUARTER' "AGGREGATION LEVEL", TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'Q'), COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'Q')
```

If my answer covers you, then please accept it.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/19903230/harry here what is the meaning of TO_CHAR

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/19903230/harry Getting error while framing this query. Could you please check once again ?

Comment: what error? Be more specific with your questions

Comment: Add to your question your expected results

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT userid,
       COUNT(1) AS count_for_previous_12_months,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_year,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_quarter,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1) THEN 1 END) AS count_for_previous_month,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_month,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '7' DAY THEN 1 END) AS count_for_previous_seven_days,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_iso_week
FROM   table_name
WHERE  datetime > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
AND    datetime <= SYSDATE
GROUP BY userid
```

If you want to remove duplicates in each week then aggregate by user and week first and then count afterwards:

```sql
SELECT userid,
       COUNT(1) AS count_for_previous_12_months,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_year,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_quarter,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1) THEN 1 END) AS count_for_previous_month,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_month,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '7' DAY THEN 1 END) AS count_for_previous_seven_days,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') THEN 1 END) AS count_for_current_iso_week
FROM   (
  SELECT userid,
         -- Remove duplicates for each week and set the datetime as the latest in each week
         MAX(datetime) AS datetime
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY userid, TRUNC(datetime, 'IW')
)
WHERE  datetime > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
AND    datetime <= SYSDATE
GROUP BY userid
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fWdsT70M)